# Writing own (kind of) DNS Server with PHP

Tags: php, dns, owncloud

I'm asking myself if it is possible to send the ip address from my router to a php script on a web hosting package (not an own server), safe it (like http://www.axelteichmann.de/DynamicDNS/index-DynDNS-mit-Fritzbox.php) and relay all incoming traffic on port 80 http and 443 https (via socket_create_listen) to the safed ip address, where my local owncloud instance (on a more powerful machine) is waiting for incoming request. I'm not quite sure if this would work. Does anyone knows that?

Comment: You're talking about writing your own reverse proxy. It can be done, but it is not as simple as it might seem.

Comment: just found out that port 1-1024 can't be listen to because you need root privileges. But I don't need that for owncloud or?

Comment: I would like to use my web hosting to redirect the domain / a subdomain to my server at home (with owncloud installed on it). My Router is the reverse proxy and my webhosting php script is a proxy. It would be perfect to use my webhosting as dns server but this seems even harder without an own manageable server.

Comment: Why does it need to be done in PHP? It's not the right language for stuff like this.

Comment: Because it's cheap. A web hosting package is much cheaper than a (dns) server. It doesn't need relaying performance as it is for about 3 active users. I could use DynDNS but thats not answering the question.

Comment: All attempts to write a complete reverse proxy in PHP have failed. Currently no solution exists. You can use rewverse proxy installations in http servers (like apache) which work very well, but that is not possible if you have rented only web space (since you have no control over the server). You need an own server for this (rented or owned, physical or virtual).

Comment: @arkascha: Ok, thanks for answer, even if it is a bit disappointing. I guess the same is holding true for other script languages as python, perl or ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting post on: http://www.phpgangsta.de/client-ip-problem-bei-reverse-proxy-betrieb
But it's also requiring changes on the underlying server.